# Using custom type for the id property

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I got the following classes:

```
public class UserId
{
    public UserId(int id){
        //some validation
    }

   public override string ToString() {}
}

public class User
{
    public UserId Id {get;set;}
}
```

How can I configure nhibernate/fluentnhibernate to use that class. The column is an int.

Comment: We could go over user types, but my general recommendation is that you don't do that. There's more to lose than to gain there.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it's a bad idea?

Comment: You'll spend time writing the usertype, only to discover that some queries don't work, or, that there are problems with caching... you'll need a perfect implementation of Equals/GetHashcode... and what do you get out of that?

Comment: OK, if you think a type for the ID is necessary for "a proper domain model", that's fine. But don't be mad when I answer "I told you so" next week :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as Diego mentioned it is not nessesaryly a good idea

```
// UserMap
Id(m => m.Id).CustomType<UserIdUserType>();


class UserIdUserType : IUserType { ... }
```