# NHibernate: how to set Id that is a property in component

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, generator

I want to set (via Fluent NHibernate) an Id to be generated: assigned.
The mapped Id is a property which contained in a component inside the entity as follows:

```
public class Group
{
    public Group()
    {
    }

    public Group(GroupIdentifier identifier)
    {
       GroupIdentifier = identifier;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual GroupIdentifier GroupIdentifier { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual IList<X> Objects { get; set; }
}

public class GroupIdentifier
{
    protected ProtectionGroupIdentifier()
    {
    }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Guid GroupGuid 
    { get; set; }

}
```

I use the following code to define the entity id:

```
.Override<Group>(obj => obj.Id(x => x.GroupIdentifier.GroupGuid).GeneratedBy.Assigned())
```

When I try to Save entity I get the following error:
threw exception. NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for property 'GroupGuid' in class...

If I move GroupGuid to Group Entity and set Id - it's working.
But I need it in GroupIdentifier component.
Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you encapsulate your GroupGuid in GroupIdentifier class, you are no longer mapping guid type, but a custom type. NHibernate needs to know how to map that custom type to database. You need to tell it how, by using NHibernate [custom value type](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-types-custom).

To learn more about NHibernate type system, read [this article](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/understanding-nhibernate-type). Google search can provide you [additional](http://blog.miraclespain.com/archive/2008/Mar-18.html) [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565056/how-to-implement-correctly-iusertype).

But, since you plan to use it for the ID property, you better double check your requirements: [Using custom type for the id property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444056/using-custom-type-for-the-id-property). Apparently that's not such a good idea.